# Processing SPI transactions using interrupts

Tags: microcontroller, pic, interrupts

I'm wondering what the best way to handle SPI transactions when using interrupts is.

I'm  about to write my SPI interface code to an external flash part using a PIC.  I'm going to use interrupts and I know that I'll get one after my byte is transferred, and after one is received.  A typical 16 bit write transaction will look like this:

```
REGISTER_ADDRESS_BYTE | REGISTER_ADDRESS_BYTE | DATA_BYTE | DATA_BYTE | MAYBE_MORE_DATA_BYTES
```

Typically what I do is have a function like this pseudo code:

```
SendBytes(num_bytes, *ptr_to_bytes, address, init_true, callback_function_address);
```

Then in my `SendBytes(...)` I have a state machine with two static variables, one keeps track of the state, the other keeps track of the number of bytes sent.  As interrupts come in I call `SendBytes(...)` again with `init_false` and step through my state machine for each byte of the transaction.  When I'm all done I either stop or call the stored `call_back_function`.

My question is this a decent way to handle this, is there a better way using interrupts?  I just made this up thinking about the problem but I assume others have had to handle this as well.

Comment: Let me back up and ask you: why do you want to use interrupt for doing the SPI master?  Polling for flags (without interrupt) is another option.  Polling tends to be simpler, arguably.

Comment: I agree that polling is easier but I want to do other real time things while my spi command is running across my relatively slow spi bus.

Comment: It seems odd to use the same function to initiate transfers and to handle the interrupts. Wouldn't it be cleaner to have separate functions?

Comment: Sure I could use two functions, I'm more curious about the state machine and static variable for state approach though.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention the PIC variant; SPI peripherals as well as interrupt controllers are different in different PICs. Here is an example of handling similar problem using PIC16:

https://github.com/felis/DMCI-XC8/blob/master/bsp.c#L91

It also shows state machine approach.

Comment: Can you sumarrize that a bit?  Link - only answers die when the link dies.

Comment: summarize what? And what is wrong with a link?

Comment: Summarize your approach.  What's wrong with links is that they can die, so a link should not be a the only piece of information in the answer.  [More about link-only answers in this post on meta.SE .](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: I have a queue which is consumed by an interrupt. When I put [the first] byte into [an empty] queue I set the interrupt [enable] flag. Actions in square brackets are architecture dependent, on some PICs it's better to disable the interrupt for the given peripheral (can't be done on PIC16).